# App with multiple .action.MAIN

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app ready and working well, and now I want to add a widget to it. The thing is, Im not sure, if I am doing this thing right, because:

- my widget would have 4 buttons, each starting a different activity from the original app
- Im aware of the additional neccessary initializations, this thing would cause, since 3 buttons would start 3 activities, that would skip the main activity
- I did add the .action.MAIN tag to my manifest, to the corresponding activities, thus I can access them

Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there any other, recommended way? The tag that I added to the manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

EDIT: forgot to mention in the original post, that the widget is a completely separate app, you would have to download it separetely from the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did add the .action.MAIN tag to my manifest, to the corresponding activities, thus I can access them

That's not a good idea, as nothing can then distinguish between them (such as your buttons in your app widget). Either use unique actions (good) or hard-wire in class names to the activities in your app widget code (not so good).

Comment: When I will be back at my developer computer, I will post some snippets from the widget, but basically what I am doing is, each button starts an Intent, which(I dont remember my exact solution here) then starts the corresponding Activity. For example, if I press the "Favorite" button on the widget, the "ActFavorites" is starting up, and if I press the "Settings" button, the "ActSettings" is starting up.


For now, it works like this, my question is, can it cause any weird errors? Lets assume I will do every neccessary initialization, so NullPointers from my source won't be an issue.

Comment: @hundeva: If you are specifically identifying your activities in the `PendingIntent`, you do not need `action.MAIN`.

Comment: If I remember right, I received some exception if I did not define the activities as action.MAIN, tho I might confuse something, I will check it tomorrow!

Comment: I did check it, if I do not add the .action.MAIN tag, than I am getting security exception.. So for now, everything is working with this manifest, hope it won't cause any problem later.